# join not giving required result when using or_like codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, join

```
$skills = explode(',', 'good listener,topper,leader');
$teacherID = 7;

function search_follower($teacherID, $skills, $limit, $start) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('student_skills.user_id');
    $this->db->from('student_skills');
    $this->db->join('followers', 'followers.student_id = student_skills.user_id', 'FULL JOIN');

    foreach ($skills as $skill) {
        $this->db->like('student_skills.name', $skill);
        $this->db->or_like('student_skills.name', $skill);
    }
    $this->db->where('followers.teacher_id', $teacherID);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

student_skills table:

`id` `name` `user_id`

`1`  `topper` `5`

`2`  `leader` `5`

`3`  `good listener` `6`

`4`  `toper` `6`

follower table:

`id` `teacher_id` `student_id`

`1`  `7` `5`

`1`  `7` `6`

`1`  `7` `8`

I have written the above model function to fetch student id's of student who follow particular teacher (`$teacherID`) and have specified skills (`$skills`) from student_skills table..

when i run the above function with multiple skills (ex: good listener, topper etc) or single skills (ex: topper) it runs without showing any error..but it gives me all the students who have the specified skills and i would like to have only the students who follow the particular teacher..and have the specified skills..

but when i comment the `or_like` statement it gives me required result but multiple skills not working.. `ex: topper` working and `ex:topper,topper` working but `ex: topper,leader` not working

I am struggling from 2 days to solve this.. but not yet came to any solutions....

any suggest or help would be a great help.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying `select` sentence.

```
$this->db->select('student_skills.*, followers.*');
```

Comment: Sir again same.. its giving me all the candidates who have the specified skills .. i would like to have the same but where followers id is teacher id