# Passing array to like active record in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I would like to pass array to `like` clause of active record in codeignter for that i have written the following:

```
$array_string = smart,intelligent,awesome;

$array_like = explode(',',$array_string);
```

and in model:

```
$this->db->like('topic',array($array_like));
```

but I am getting

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
```

Any help or suggestion would be a great help.

See updated question here:
[join not giving required result when using or_like codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416415/join-not-giving-required-result-when-using-or-like-codeigniter)

Comment: `$array_like` is already an array because of `explode()`, perhaps changing your `$this->db->like('topic',array($array_like));` to `$this->db->like('topic',$array_like)`; might be a good start.

Comment: @dqlopez i have tried but again array to strign converstion notice is coming

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't just pass an array to the `like()` function, it has to be a string. You need to apply a `like` clause for each of the keywords in the string.

You need to use `or_like` to match a record to either of the keywords, however, because if you just use `like()` each time, it will need to match all of the keywords due to the query being like `LIKE "%smart" AND LIKE "%intelligent"` etc. and that isn't what you require.

```
$array_string = "smart,intelligent,awesome";
$array_like = explode(',', $array_string);
foreach($array_like as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 0) {
        $this->db->like('topic', $value);
    } else {
        $this->db->or_like('topic', $value);
    }
}
```

Try this way to avoid your problem of the rest of the `where` statement being ignored.

```
$array_string = "smart,intelligent,awesome";
$array_like = explode(',', $array_string);

$like_statements = array();

foreach($array_like as $value) {
    $like_statements[] = "topic LIKE '%" . $value . "%'";
}

$like_string = "(" . implode(' OR ', $like_statements) . ")";
```

The value of `$like_string` will be `(topic LIKE '%smart%' OR topic LIKE '%intelligent%' OR topic LIKE '%awesome%')`

You can then use `$like_string` in the following way with ActiveRecord:

```
$this->db->where($like_string, FALSE);
```

Comment: thank you very much sir i am getting databse error:::

Comment: see full question here::: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416415/join-not-giving-required-result-when-using-or-like-codeigniter

Comment: @Ryan: don't forget to escape `$value` variable `$this->db->escape($value)`. @Muhammad: we are not obligated to answer your questions, please don't be rude.

Comment: i fully agree @machineaddict Sir.... and thank you very much for your important time..sir

Comment: @Ryan Sir, `(topic LIKE '%smart%' OR topic LIKE '%intelligent%' OR topic LIKE '%awesome%')` this helps me lot.. but i am getting 1 extra like at the end:: `(topic LIKE '%smart%' OR topic LIKE '%intelligent%' OR topic LIKE '%awesome%') LIKE %%`

Comment: i have used `$this->db->like($like_string, FALSE);` instead of your code: '$this->db->where($like_string, FALSE);'

Comment: @Ryan Sir , i have solved the issue.. by removing `FALSE' from the where query.. and thank you very much i have been struggling to solve this issue from last 5 days..today i got the result...many many thanks sir... but one question what does the `FALSE` is instructing here to the database

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Codeigniter 2.1.4, as you can read in [CodeIgniter active record documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html), you cannot pass the second argument as array in like function. You need to pass a string as argument.

```
$array_string = "smart,intelligent,awesome";
$array_like = explode(',', $array_string);

foreach ($array_like as $like)
{
    $this->db->like('topic', $like);
}
```

Comment: i have already tried this.. and this works for me when i pass only one  value ex: `smart` and when i pass 3 of them or 2 ex: `smart,awesome,etc` then no result is coming..

Comment: That is because you might not have anything in database that matches `topic LIKE "%smart%" AND topic LIKE "%intelligent%" AND topic LIKE "%awesome%"`

Comment: Then put all the code in your original question. Also, it might help if you print your query AFTER execution like this `echo $this->db->last_query();` and run it in `phpMyAdmin`.